# mysql grant sql script to user not working

Tags: mysql, sql

the title says it all, here was my code

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON 'database_name' TO 'mysqluser'@'111.111.111.111';
```

it says

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax near ''database_name' TO 'mysqluser'@'111.111.111.111'' at line 1
```

Comment: Umm.. take the quotes off of `database_name`?

Comment: error : no database selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON 'database_name' TO 'mysqluser'@'111.111.111.111';
```

Should be:

```
GRANT ALL ON 'database_name'.* TO 'mysqluser'@'111.111.111.111';
```

In your specific case(tested on my mysql server):

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON database_name.* TO 'mysqluser'@'111.111.111.111';
```

Comment: but i only need those four only.

Answer (score 1):

You quoted the DB name with `'`, which turns it into a string. Once it's a string, it's no longer a table name. it's just a string that CONTAINS something that looks like a table name.

It should be EITHER

```
GRANT ... ON database_name
or
GRANT ... ON `database_name`
```

The backticks are only necessary if the db name happens to be a reserved word.